# Laravel Testing with PHPUnit assert correct order

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I have defined a scope which sorty my entities by a published_at timestamp. I wanted to write a test to ensure correct ordering.

However I somehow fail to find a "nice" way to do this.

```
$novels = Novel::published()->get();
```

This is my best guess

```
for($i = 1; $i < count($novels); $i++) 
{
    $this->assertGreaterThanOrEqual(
        $novels->toArray()[$i - 1]['published_at'], 
        $novels->toArray()[$i]['published_at']
    );
}
```

Can anyone provide a better way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't anything wrong with what you're doing in your test if it works.

That being said, if you want to shorten your test you could do something like:

```
$this->assertEquals(
    $novels->pluck('id'),
    $novels->sortBy('published_at')->pluck('id'),
    'The Novels are not being ordered by published_at date'
);
```